# Is defining a decorator anonymously(with lambda experession) possible in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, nested, anonymous-function, python-decorators

First of all, I want to explain to you that I test my "***`lambda` has all attribute of function if `lambda` defined as `<class 'function'>`***" idea. That's why I ask that question. I want to define a decorator anonymously(with `lambda` expression). defining `nested lambda` was the first idea which I found. Does `nested lambda`work or is there any idea else which you can suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't really if it can be done, (it can) the question is why would you want to?

Here is an example of a `lambda` as a simple decorator using a `tuple` as a hack to get 2 statements in one line.

```
foo = lambda func: lambda: (print('Hello'), func())

@foo
def bar():
    print('World')

bar()
```

Comment: I want to do it. Because I wondered and want to test it. But then, It's really useful.  Thank you to satisfied my curiosity.